# Background color isn't inherited into children tags

Tags: html, css

I have split my footer tag into 2 seperate tags, 1 being a disclaimer and the other being contact but the children tags wont inherit the background color i want to set.

```
<footer role="contentinfo" id="contentinfo">
<div class="disclaimer">
</div>
<div class="contact">
</div>
</footer>  



footer {
color: #FFF8BF;
width: 100%;
padding:0 px;
background-color: #1C1C1C;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
bottom: 0;
display: block;
 /*border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px ;*/
}

.disclaimer {
float: left;
color: white;
max-width: 50%;
}

.contact {

color:white;
float:right;
text-align: left;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
margin: 0px;
max-width: 50%;
}
```

Thanks for any help

> Blockquote

Comment: your footer has 0px height because float elements causes this so give height to footer or clear float for variable height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you set a `height` of the footer:

**CSS**

```
footer {
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Or you could insert **content**  into the footers' children and set the `overflow:auto` property for the footer

**HTML**

```
<footer role="contentinfo" id="contentinfo">
<div class="disclaimer">
    Sample content
</div>
<div class="contact">
    Sample content
</div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
footer {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fz07hwhp/1/).

Comment: Thanks, i've added the overflow to it and now its working perfectly.

Comment: Unless he wants only the divs to be coloured. That way the whole footer is going to be coloured no?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the background color is shown in your child divs, but since you are using `float` in them, and didn't set a specific height on your footer, the height of your footer is 0 since floating elements don't expand the parent container. At least not for `block` elements. Unless you set a different `display` attribute like `display: table`.

so change your footer class to:

```
footer {
   color: #FFF8BF;
   width: 100%;
   padding:0 px;
   background-color: #1C1C1C;
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   bottom: 0;
   display: table;                          // <---- change this to table instead of block
  /*border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px ;*/
}
```

Comment: background color property is non inherited

Comment: this is because child div are transparent by default. and read more here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: well i replaced inherited with "shown". your right that transparent is the default value. Nevertheless the core statements of my answer (missing height of footer and one way to solve it) are still solid i guess.

Comment: thanks for the reply, This also seems to work as i wanted, but i think the overflow option looks like the better option

Answer (score 0):

```
Background color property cannot be inherited
```

you can achieve what you want by adding this in your code before closing footer tag

```
<br style='clear:both'></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a height at the moment, as the `content` and `disclaimer` are empty

if you add `overflow:auto;` with `footer` it will work. Try giving a `width` and `height`. Also for testing you can always add a `border: 1px solid red;` or something

EDIT: For now instead of `max-width` use `width` or `min-width` as with `max-width` the max width will be 50% yes BUT it can be 0% as it is in this case